# Why is the converting constructor preferred to the conversion operator?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator, explicit-constructor

I have this class `SmallInt` that should represent a positive integer value in the range `0-255`-inclusive:

```
struct SmallInt{
    explicit SmallInt(int x = 0) : iVal_( !(x < 0 || x > 255) ? x :
    throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(x) + ": value outbounds!")){}
    operator int&() { return iVal_; }
    int iVal_;
};

int main(){

    try{
        SmallInt smi(7);
        cout << smi << '\n';
        cout << smi + 5 << '\n'; // 7 + 5 = 12
        cout << smi + 5.88 << '\n'; // 7.0 + 5.88 = 12.88
        smi = 33; // error: constructor is explicit
        smi.operator int&() = 33;
        cout << smi << '\n';
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error const& re){
        std::cout << re.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

- What matters me is: why can I assign to `smi` explicitly calling `operator int&`: `smi.operator int&() = 33` but not implicitly: `smi = 33;`?
- The first expression (`smi = 33;`) complains about the constructor `SmallInt(int)` begin `explicit`; I know that but I have the conversion operator that returns a modifiable plain lvalue. So in other words why in such an implicit assignment is the constructor preferred to the conversion operator?

Comment: This question probably should have the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: wild guess: `33` is of type `int&&`, not `int&`

Comment: @Raildex It's a prvalue of type `int`. Expressions can't have reference types.

Comment: @Raildex: Yes I know it is a prvalue but  a prvalue can be assigned to a modifiable lvalue of  a related type.

Comment: small guess : your operator int&() is within your class, so it has no reason to convert it as it is not in the right side

Comment: I suppose `smi = 33;` is interpreted as `smi.operator=(33);`, which has to convert `33` to `SmallInt` to be able to pass the argument, and thus looks for a suitable constructor.

Comment: if you add an explicit type casting it works : `(int&) smi = 33;` so I guess it only try to cast the right side of the operator= which make sense as you don't want to cast the value you want to assign to

Comment: `smi =` calls for assignment. There is an implicit assignment generated `SmallInt& operator=(const SmallInt&)` which is a candidate. To use it, the compiler tries to adjust the right hand side. The only candidate is `explicit SmallInt(int x = 0)` but it cannot be used as being `explicit`. You could overload the assignment, or you could make the constructor implicit so that it can be used for conversion.

Comment: `smi = 33` will call an `operator=(int)` if one exists. That doesn't exist in your case, so it will try `smi = SmallInt(33)` which *implicitly* constructs a temporary (`SmallInt(33)`) and uses `operator=(const SmallInt &)` (or similar) to assign `smi` as a copy of the temporary. Constructing the temporary fails in your case because the constructor that accepts an `int` is `explicit`.  No "conversion operator" (your `operator int &()`) is used, since conversions only happen to the right hand side of the assignment. If you want to use that operator do something like `(int &)smi = 33`.

Comment: `operator=` cannot be a non member. Every use of it is equivalent a member access. It's the same as asking why `a.foo()` cannot compile if `A` has `operator B&` and `B` has a `foo` method.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `!(x < 0 || x > 255)` really should be written `x >= 0 0 && x <= 255`.

Comment: Side note: what is the advantage of `SmallInt` over the basic `uint8_t`? Detecting overflow? In this case, the `operator int&()` should also perform check.

Comment: @laenNoCode: `static_cast<int&>(smi) = 57;` This works just fine but is well-defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **[over.match.oper]/4** For the built-in assignment operators, conversions of the left operand are restricted as follows:
> ...
> (4.2) — no user-defined conversions are applied to the left operand to achieve a type match with the left-most
> parameter of a built-in candidate.

Thus `(int &)smi = 33` interpretation is explicitly prohibited from consideration by the standard.

Comment: So although this `static_cast<int&>(smi) = 57;` works. does it mean it is non-standard? And I shouldn't do that?

Comment: This talks about overload resolution, and implicit conversion sequences considered as part of the same. You can of course convert explicitly.

Comment: Ok well thank you!